# Ist es falsch, statt des Konjunktivs in indirekter Rede den Indikativ zu verwenden?

Tags: subjunctive, verb-usage, indirect-speech

In der Schule haben wir im Geschichtsunterricht gelernt, dass wir den Konjunktiv (z. B. *sei*) verwenden sollen, wenn wir indirekt zitieren, was andere Leute gesagt haben; bspw.:

> In Quelle 1 wird behauptet, dass … die Ursache für die Industrialisierung *sei*.

Aber was ist an folgendem Satz falsch?

> In Quelle 1 wird behauptet, dass … die Ursache für die Industrialisierung *ist*.

Es wird schließlich behauptet, dass … die Ursache für die Industrialisierung ist!

---

Und wie siehts mit dem folgenden Satz aus?

> Die Aussage, dass jede Gruppe abelsch ist, ist falsch.

Muss da statt *ist* eigentlich auch *sei* stehen? Gefühlsmäßig ist die Aussage so meiner Meinung nach vollkommen in Ordnung.

Comment: Mich würde wundern, wenn nicht irgendwo eine Dublette rumliegen würde, aber ich bin gerade zu faul zum suchen …

Comment: Im Fall der abelschen Gruppen liegt ja keine indirekte Rede vor. "Der Professor sagte, dass jede Gruppe abelsch sei" wäre eine. Ob auch _ist_ erlaubt ist, weiß ich nicht, ich würde sagen es ist weit verbreitet.

Answer (score 2):

In bestimmten Fällen kannst du den Indikativ verwenden und das ist so, wie du oben schreibst, in den Fällen, wo der Nebensatz mit *dass* beginnst.

Dazu habe ich folgendes auf *lehrerfreund*gefunden:

> In der indirekten Rede "und ähnlichen Nebensätzen, die durch eine unterordnende Konjunktion (dass,ob) oder ein Fragewort (was, wann, wie u. ä.) eingeleitet werden" dürfen sowohl Konjunktiv I als auch der Indikativ verwendet werden.

Ausnahmen sind Verben wie *wissen, erfahren, einsehen*, wo immer der Konjunktiv benötigt wird.

Daraus schließe ich, dass deine Sätze alle mit Indikativ verwendet werden können.

Comment: Herzlich willkommen auf german.se! - Gute Antwort, aber wenn Du die Quelle verlinken - und eventuell sogar die Primärquelle statt einer Sekundärquelle fändest - wäre sie noch besser!

Answer (score 2):

Man kann sowohl Konjunktiv 1 als auch 2 eigentlich immer durch den Indikativ ersetzen. So lehrt es uns die gesprochene Sprache.

> Richtig, aber schnöselig: Er hat gesagt, [er sei verhindert] / [dass er verhindert sei].
>
> Richtig, neutral: Er hat gesagt, [er ist verhindert] / [dass er verhindert ist].

Für die Schrift gebe ich dir mal folgende Direktiven mit auf den Weg:

– Konjunktiv 1 bei ausdrücklichem Zitat

> Donald Trump: »Ich bin bald der mächtigste Mann der Welt.«
>
> --› Donald Trump sagte, er sei bald der mächtigste Mann der Welt.
>
> --› Donald Trump sagte, dass er bald der mächtigste Mann der Welt sei.

– Ansonsten je nach Geschmack Konjunktiv oder Indikativ

> Die Aussage, Trump sei ein Hitzkopf, ist aus der Luft gegriffen.
>
> Die Aussage, dass Trump ein Hitzkopf ist, ist aus der Luft gegriffen.

Wenn du tatsächlich zitierst (das heißt du verdrehst den Quellen nicht die Worte im Mund), solltest du zur Kenntlichmachung Konjunktiv 1 verwenden. Ansonsten geh schlicht nach Gefühl vor. Was passend klingt, kann man von Fall zu Fall entscheiden.